# Using @jointable with all columns non unique

Tags: mysql, jpa, join

Im trying to create a Survey. The Survey is made of a Collection of Questions. 
Each Question in turn is made of a Collection of Answer Values.

I have tied the Questions to Survey like this:

```
@OneToMany()
@JoinTable(
        name = "survey_question_list",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "survey_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "question_list_id"))
private Collection<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

In the same way I have tied Answervalues to each Question:

```
@OneToMany()
@JoinTable(
        name = "question_answer_value_list",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "question_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "answer_value_list_id"))
private Collection<AnswerValue> answerValueList = new ArrayList<AnswerValue>();
```

The Tables are created in the Database as I want them: Survey IDs tied to Question Ids and Question Ids tied to Answervalue Ids.

My Problem is that I get the following error:

```
enteorg.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_eky8oymsfv24p3r4by54m15ta' 
Query is: insert into question_answer_value_list (question_id, answer_value_list_id) values (?, ?), parameters [2,1]
```

The Problem I see is that one of the Ids is Unique, which dissallows for multiple equal ids.
Yet I need to Map each question to a possible answer, which means that both Question Ids and Answer Ids must appear multiple times.
Example:
If Question 1 and Question 2 have 3 possible answers then the mapping would look like this:

```
Question_Id  Answer_Value_Id
1            1
1            2
1            3
2            1
2            2
2            3
etc.         etc.
```

How can I change the Table to allow for this?

EDIT:
Here is the Logic of my Survey build:

```
@RequestMapping("/createsurvey2")
public Survey createSurvey2() {
    Survey survey = new Survey();
    survey.setName("My First Survey");
    // surveyRepository.save(survey);

    AnswerValue answerValue1 = new AnswerValue(1);

    answerValueRepository.save(answerValue1);

    Question question1 = new Question();
    question1.setQuestionContent("Was the Meeting Helpful?");
    question1.addAnswerValue(answerValue1);

    questionRepository.save(question1);

    survey.addQuestion(question1);

    Question question2 = new Question();
    question2.setQuestionContent("Was the Meeting Horrible?");
    questionRepository.save(question2);
    question2.addAnswerValue(answerValue1);

    questionRepository.save(question2);

    survey.addQuestion(question2);

    Question question3 = new Question();
    question3.setQuestionContent("Was the Meeting Funny?");
    questionRepository.save(question3);
    question3.addAnswerValue(answerValue1);

    questionRepository.save(question3);

    survey.addQuestion(question3);


    surveyRepository.save(survey);

    return survey;
}
```

Comment: So, you are expecting that Question 1 and Question 2 have the same set of Answers? From a high level concept, does that make sense for your model?

Comment: Also, it depends on what you are doing with these entities. Can you provide your logic to create these objects?

Comment: Please see Edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the following:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();

Answer a1 = new Answer(1, "Federal");
Answer a2 = new Answer(2, "State");
Answer a3 = new Answer(3, "Local");

List<Answer> q1_answers = Arrays.asList(a1, a2, a3);
Question q1 = new Question(1, q1_answers);

List<Answer> q2_answers = Arrays.asList(a1, a2, a3);
Question q2 = new Question(2, q2_answers);

List<Question> questions = Arrays.asList(q1, q2);
Survey s = new Survey(1, questions);

em.persist(s);

em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Using this in a simple Junit test, I was able to create the following table just fine:

```
QUESTION_ID ANSWER_VALUE_LIST_ID
1                   1
1                   2
1                   3
2                   1
2                   2
2                   3
```

Note: I used cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST on the @OneToMany relationships:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
```